# Not updating SQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

For some reason my code isn't updating mySQL database, but it isn't reporting any errors.

**register.php** (form)

```
        <form class="register_form" action="action.php?do=register" method="post">
            Team Name*: <input type="text" name="teamname" required />
            Team Region*: <input type="text" name="teamregion" maxlength="4" required />
            Team Leader*: <input type="text" name="teamleader" maxlength="16" required />
            Team Members: <input type="text" name="teammembers"  />
            <input name="register_submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
        </form>
```

**action.php**

```
    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("192.185.#.###","########_reg","#######","#########");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();}
            $action = $_GET['do'];
                if($action=="register") {
                    $teamname = $_POST["teamname"];
                    $teamregion = $_POST["teamregion"];
                    $teamleader = $_POST["teamleader"];
                    $teammembers = $_POST["teammembers"];
                        $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO teams (teamname, region, teamleader, teammembers, wins, loses)
                        VALUES (" . $teamname . "," . $teamregion . "," . $teamleader . "," . $teammembers . ",0,0);");
                }
    ?>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working correctly?

Comment: No, but ffs, use prepared statements!

Comment: As a side note,mysqli has prepared statements,use them.

Comment: As an aside, your code here appears to be vulnerable to sql injection. When using inline sql to need to ensure that the user cannot enter values that mess about with your sql statements, causing the server to perform updates, inserts and other commands that are malicious.

Comment: Unless you use prepared statements/bind variables, you need to escape and wrap string values in quotes in your SQL statement.... the moral, use bind variables

Comment: @Mihai: what do you mean by prepared statement?

Comment: @ursitesion http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Comment: One of those "Hope for the best answer and `wish` for the best". Too many things wrong with this. Not putting in an answer, nor any suggestion(s), except for "read and most importantly `Understand` the tutorials"; PHP & MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working sample with prepared statements, that are "better" to use generally instead of `query`

**action.php**

```
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dachi');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] === "register") {
    $teamname = $_POST["teamname"];
    $teamregion = $_POST["teamregion"];
    $teamleader = $_POST["teamleader"];
    $teammembers = $_POST["teammembers"];
    $wins = 0;
    $loses = 0;

    $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `teams` (`teamname`,`region`,`teamleader`,`teammembers`,`wins`,`loses`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $teamname, $teamregion, $teamleader, $teammembers, $wins, $loses);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

**register.php**

```
<form class="register_form" action="action.php?do=register" method="post">
    Team Name*: <input type="text" name="teamname" required />
    Team Region*: <input type="text" name="teamregion" maxlength="4" required />
    Team Leader*: <input type="text" name="teamleader" maxlength="16" required />
    Team Members: <input type="text" name="teammembers"  />
    <input name="register_submit" type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should be able to GET it

Answer (score 0):

You should change:

```
if($action=="register") {
```

to

```
if($action=="register_submit") {
```

Because your input has a tag name set to value *register_submit* not *register*.

and change `$action = $_GET['do'];` to `$action = $_POST['register_submit'];`

Comment: but it is checking for "do" on action.php which is set to "register" ?

Answer (score 0):

**register.php (form)**

```
<form class="register_form" action="action.php?do=register" method="post">
```

**action.php**

```
$action = $_GET['do'];
```