# SQL Error bind_param()

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have an error in my action.php - Wondered if some of you could help.

**action.php**

```
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] === "reg_type_2") {
     $teamname = $_POST["teamname"];
     $teamregion = $_POST["teamregion"];
     $teamleader = $_POST["teamleader"];
     $teammember = $_POST["teammember"];
     $wins = 0;
     $loses = 0;

     $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `team_type_2` (`teamname`,`region`,`teamleader`,`teammember`,`wins`,`loses`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
     $stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $teamname, $teamregion, $teamleader, $teammember, $wins, $loses);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->close();
 }
```

**Error:** `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /home1/tony1964/public_html/2v2tournaments/action.php on line 38`

-

*Line 38 is `$stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $teamname, $teamregion, $teamleader, $teammember, $wins, $loses);`*

Comment: That's a PHP error, not a SQL error. How do you verify whether `prepare()` succeeds?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - I used this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21367060/2995986 from before.. It worked fine, now not so much.

Comment: Add before `bind_param` line: `if($stmt === FALSE){ die($con->error); }`

Comment: @RocketHazmat doesn't that just close the connection if it doesn't work?

Comment: @Night: The `die` will exit your script, yes.  It's just for debugging, though.  You can display the error message how you wish.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, ight thanks xD

Comment: @Night: It's just so we can see what the error message is (if any).

Comment: What are the values ​​of variables coming? The MySql is crashing at the moment of preparing the query. Also, you realize that you have data in POST and GET data

Comment: Maybe you misspelled '$conn' in $con->prepare ?

Comment: Nothing is misspelled, the variables are coming from a `POST form`